# How to print binary for each address using Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I have problem about displaying every bits in QT. For example, I receive this binary number `10011101`.
Therefore I want to display it like this:

address 0 = `1`
address 1 = `0`
address 2 = `0`
address 3 = `1`
address 4 = `1`
address 5 = `1`
address 6 = `0`
address 7 = `1`

I know how to do it using C and of course it is different when using Qt.

Comment: Why don't you use your C implementation?

Comment: How is it different in Qt? C is a subset of C++, and C++ is used in Qt.

Comment: i tried but cannot.maybe because originally it use qt.

Comment: i am using Qtcreator

Comment: @nurshazwani, With Qtcreator, you can use the C++ standard, is not a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your binary representation is a string:

```
QString s = "10011101";
```

If your binary representation is an int:

```
int val = 10011101;
QString s = QString("%1").arg(val);
```

Print it:

```
// address ... = ...
for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++)
    cout << "address " << i << " = " << s.at(i).toLatin1() << endl;
```

Comment: when I use cout it said that i didnt declare it. I have to display it in my UI, so  i did ` ui->textEdit->append("address %1" + (s.at(i).toLatin1()));`
but it shows
values is 0 (repeatedly)

Comment: @nurshazwani, Include ```<iostream>``` and write ```std::cout``` if you don't using namespace ```std```. But if you want to display it in your UI, write: ```ui->textEdit->append(QString("address %1 = %2").arg(i, s.at(i).toLatin1()));```

Comment: it display address 0 = %2

Comment: @nurshazwani, Write a minimal example of your code please... It's should be work, try to remove ```toLatin1()``` when you use only Qt

Comment: `QString hexadecimalNumber = hexVal;
              bool ok = false;
              QString binaryNumber = QString::number(hexadecimalNumber.toLongLong(&ok, 16), 2);
              ui->textEdit->append(binaryNumber);`

Comment: i want to display the `binaryNumber` in the address

Comment: @nurshazwani, Edit your post please, but int the loop, try with two ```arg``` like this: ```ui->textEdit->append(QString("address %1 = %2").arg(i).arg(s.at(i)));```

Comment: yes i got it,,,fell that i wanna cry,, i have been trying for 2 weeks, thankyou

Comment: and sory this is my first time posting here. tq